# How do you Parse an Array of Dictionaries in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm new to swift and I am having difficulty parsing an array the array looks like this

MyArray [
[0]9keyValuePairs
[1]9keyValuePairs
]

I would like to add "MyArray.(0).ValueForKey:"Name" " to a UITableViewCell, but I can't quite figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Assuming this is what you mean `[[Key:Value]]` you would do `yourArray[index][key]` to get the value

Comment: Also, you can read up on collection types for swift. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your array declared? If it is a array of something generic, ie `[AnyObject]` then you need to tell the type checker that the object in the array is a dictionary by casting it, otherwise you wont be able to access it as a dictionary.

If it is explicitly declared as an array of dictionaries ie `[[String:AnyObject]]` , then you just need to access the element in the array that you want, and then access the dictionary element you are interested in.

```
array[0] //how to get something out of an array
dictionary[key] //how to get something out of a dict
array[0][key] //how to get something out of an array of dicts

// if your array contents need to be cast, safely cast it using optional unwrapping 
if let dict = array[0] as? [String:AnyObject] { 
    dict[key]
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is the exactly what I was missing. Much appreciated.